# Cloudinary API transformation issues

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

I'm using Cloudinary as a image storage for my app but I'm having issues to transform my images.

What I would like to achieve is:

- if an image is bigger than 1920px width (considering it like a landscape image): width should be crop to 1920px (maintaining the ratio);
- if an image is bigger than 1920px height (considering it like a portrait image): height should be crop to 1920px (maintaining the ratio);
- format to be always `jpg`;
- quality reduced to 80 to decrease image weight.

my current integration is:

```
const transformation = {
  width: 1920, max_height: 1920, format: 'jpg', quality: 80
};
```

But unfortunately this output is a squared image...

I'm trying to use `if` but I don't understand how should be used... it looks like that writing documentations is always the hardest thing to do...

I hope you can help me to find the right approach. I'm using the SDK, so all plain javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a `max_height` parameter in the SDK when creating transformations, but you can achieve what you're looking for by setting both `width` and `height` to the maximum value you want to allow.

If you're getting a square output, it's because the default [crop/resize mode](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#resizing_and_cropping_images) is `scale`, which produces an output in exactly the dimensions requested, but may result in the image being 'squashed' or 'stretched'.

What I think you're looking for here is something like this:

```
const transformation = {
  width: 1920, height: 1920, format: 'jpg', quality: 'auto', crop: 'limit'
};
```

Which gives you a URL like this:
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_1920,h_1920,f_jpg,q_auto,c_limit/bike.jpg

The 'limit' crop mode will scale the image down (not up) until it's smaller than 1920x1920, and will keep the original aspect ratio

Comment: It is good this approach, yes! Now the issue is to modify a provider not using npm... it is a neverending story... Thanks